# Why is my javascript code ignoring the if?

Tags: javascript

> A new user is supposed to be created and added to the array if it hasn't been added before, but for some reason my code ignores the if that asks if it is in the (Array.prototype.includes ()) and adds the new user independently whether it existed before or not. I have already checked that the array is stored correctly in localStorage, also that the users are being created correctly. I can see it's a lot of code, sorry about that, but I can't really think of anywhere else to look for the error. It's for a school job and I must do it the way it is there

```js
function Usuario(name, lname, age, rol, user, pass) {
  this.name = name;
  this.lname = lname;
  this.age = age;
  this.rol = rol;
  this.user = user;
  this.pass = pass;
}
var usuarios = localStorage.getItem("usuarios");
usuarios = (usuarios) ? JSON.parse(usuarios) : [];

function crearUsuario() {
  var n = document.getElementById("newU_name").value;
  var l = document.getElementById("newU_lname").value;
  var a = document.getElementById("newU_age").value;
  var r = document.getElementById("newU_rol").value;
  var u = document.getElementById("newU_user").value;
  var p = document.getElementById("newU_pass").value;
  var new_user = new Usuario(n, l, a, r, u, p);
  return new_user;
}

function addUsuario() {
  var u = crearUsuario();
  console.log(u);
  if (usuarios.includes(u)) { //this is what is ignored
    window.alert("Exist");
  } else {
    usuarios.push(u);
    localStorage.setItem("usuarios", JSON.stringify(usuarios));
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>
    administrar
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Usuario Nuevo</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nombre(s):</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="newU_name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Apellidos::</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="newU_lname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Edad:</label>
            <input type="age" name="age" id="newU_age" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Rol:</label>
            <select name="rol" id="newU_rol" class="form-control">
              <option value="Ayudante">Alumno Ayudante</option>
              <option value="Profesor">Profesor</option>
              <option value="Admin">Administrador</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Usuario:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" id="newU_user" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="newU_pass" class="form-control">
            <br>
            <label type="text" id="uss"></label>
          </div>
          <button type="reset" id="btn_reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
          <input type="button" id="btn_ok" class="btn btn-default" value="Aceptar" onclick="addUsuario()">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code below, need to made sure usuarios is not undefine and has includes function.

```
function addUsuario() {
  var u = crearUsuario();
  console.log(u);
  if (usuarios.includes(u)) { //this is what is ignored
    window.alert("Exist");
  } else {
    usuarios.push(u);
    localStorage.setItem("usuarios", JSON.stringify(usuarios));
  }
}
```

Console to tracking, and need to add more compare condition like this:

```
function addUsuario() {
  var u = crearUsuario();
  console.log(u);
  console.log(usuarios); //see your object in console panel is correct?
  if (typeof(usuarios) !== "undefined" && typeof(usuarios.includes) === "function" && usuarios.includes(u)) { //this is what is ignored
    window.alert("Exist");
  } else {
    usuarios.push(u);
    localStorage.setItem("usuarios", JSON.stringify(usuarios));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could lie in the fact that you are checking if a complex object array includes another complex object.

instead of includes try something like

```
if (usuarios.some(x => x.attribute === y.attribute)) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since usuarios is an array of users, each user is an object. You cannot check using `includes`. You need to search using a `findIndex` or `find` or a simple `for` loop.

You need to specify which field is unique, I've assumed `user` is a unique field.

```js
function addUsuario() {
  var u = crearUsuario();
  console.log(u);
  const exists = (usuarios.findIndex((lu) => lu.user === u.user )) > -1;
  if (exists) { //this is what is ignored
    window.alert("Exist");
  } else {
    usuarios.push(u);
    localStorage.setItem("usuarios", JSON.stringify(usuarios));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.includes()` will not work with an array of objects.
When it comes to object `{a:1,b:2} == {a:1,b:2}` will return false. Both point to different address in memory. Similary array of objects cannot find an object inside it with .includes().

If you have a unique key (probably `.user`), you might want to search using that with `.findIndex()` or you will have to manually compare all the keys.